# Why does instanceof operator in Javascript behaves strangely?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I have this code:

```js
function Foo () { }

function Bar() { }

Bar.prototype = new Foo();

var foo = new Foo();
var bar = new Bar();
bar instanceof Bar; // true
bar instanceof Foo; // true
```

Why and how does the 'instanceof' operator return true for Bar? I replace the '.prototype' property of Bar with a new empty object created by Foo, so how does the 'instanceof' operator knows that i called Bar to instantiate the object? My understanding of 'instanceof' till now was that it examines the **proto** chain of an object and checks for the '.constructor' property on them. But in this case, Bar.prototype is an empty object, not containing the '.constructor' property that refers to Bar. Does this have to do with the implementation of 'instanceof' operator itself or I am mistaken somewhere?

Comment: _"prototype is an empty object,"_ no, it's an instance of Foo that has no properties

Comment: `bar instanceof Bar` checks whether `Bar.prototype` is in the prototype chain of `bar`. And of course it is since you just did `var bar = new Bar();`. `Object.getPrototypeOf(bar) === Bar.prototype`. `constructor` doesn't have anything to do with this.

Comment: `But in this case, Bar.prototype is an empty object, not containing the '.constructor' property that refers to Bar.` This is incorrect. Although `Bar.prototype`, that is, `new Foo()`, doesn't have any properties directly on the object, that object's *prototype* (the class Foo) *does* have a constructor property.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Bar.prototype is an empty object linked to the Foo.prototype object which contains '.constructor' property that points to Foo.

Comment: @RobinZigmond That's exactly what I am saying.

Comment: FWIW, here is the specification for `instanceof`: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-instanceofoperator

Comment: @FelixKling I don't quite get what you said. My understanding is that that instanceof checks every proto on the chain and looks for the .constructor property on it to find where it points to, so this is the way it knows if an object was constructed with a certain function. So if Bar.prototype is empty, it doesn't contain the '.constructor' property. Then how does it return true?

Comment: Oh yeah. But I think @FelixKling is correct on how `instanceof` actually works. But don't think about it too hard - imo trying to "fake" classical OO patterns in JS like this always leads to confusion. I also think it's largely unnecessary - and if you really need it, ES6 gives a much nicer syntax with the `class` keyword :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Comment: @Felix Kling I may now get it but that means that I was wrong that instanceof checks for the .constructor property to decide? You probably meant that when i check instanceof against Bar, it checks basically Bar.prototype === bar.__proto__?

Comment: @RobinZigmond No, it returns false, and it is correct that way, because Bar.prototype is an empty object and new only executes the constructor function on the newly created object. It sets the newly created object as this and executes the constructor function on it. It doesn't do anything else.

Comment: *"it checks basically Bar.prototype === bar.__proto__"* Yes. And it does that "recursively, i.e. it also checks `Bar.prototype === bar.__proto__.__proto__`, ... until the comparison is `true` or it reaches the end of the prototype chain. And that is the reason why `bar instanceof Foo` is `true` as well.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, I forgot to add that too. Thanks to all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

here prototype chain is  bar.__proto__ -->  **Bar.prototype** --> Bar.prototype.__proto__ --> **Foo.prototype**-->Object.prototype --> null

> The instanceof operator tests whether the prototype property of a constructor appears anywhere in the prototype chain of an object.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

```
bar instanceof Bar;
```

so, does prototype property of Bar constructor (**Bar.prototype**), appear anywhere in the prototype chain of bar? and it is there in this chain in bold.

```
bar instanceof Foo;
```

so, does prototype property of Foo constructor (**Foo.prototype**), appear anywhere in the prototype chain of bar? and it is there in this chain in bold.

Also note, here constructor of Foo or Bar are not important, only the prototypes in the chain of bar matter.

Comment: In *"as "prototype property of Bar" is Foo"* you are probably referring to the Foo in the output `__proto__: Foo` but that's a but confusing (and I blame Chrome's devtools there). Of course the prototype is not `Foo` itself but an instance of `Foo` (namely `new Foo()` as you mention later).

Comment: removed console image, not giving enough info